# selenium webdriver it shows an error for gmail login scrript

Tags: selenium

When ever I'm trying to login run gmail login case it shows an error

selenium web driver it shows an error for gmail login script

[image: issue appear]

Comment: Welcome to Superuser! Please take the [tour](https://superuser.com/tour), to know which questions are meant here.

Answer (score 2):

You need to escape it so that

```
"c:\\Web drivers\\chromedriver.exe"
```

Please look into [this](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/data/characters.html). `\` is the escape character for string.